# iTextSharp signing in c#: example fails with "DER length more than 4 bytes: 109"

Tags: itext

I am using the example listed on SourceForge ("from the Digital Signatures for PDF documents" white paper, examples ported from Java to C#) to sign a PDF file:

http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/chapter2/C2_01_SignHelloWorld/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.cs

However, the signing fails with the following error:

**DER length more than 4 bytes: 109**

The keystore was created using the keytool as indicated on page 17 of the white paper, which should be OK for the example "the Hello World of signing with iText".

Has anyone had the same problem before with the ported examples ?

Thanks,
Koen Lowie.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace showing where exactly the sample failed?

Comment: I am doing some further debugging now. The call that fails is the following:  `Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store store = new Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store(new FileStream(@"C:\ks", FileMode.Open), "mypassword".ToCharArray());`  The _c:\ks_ file was created as follows:  `keytool -genkey -alias GSCDemo -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore ks`

Comment: I have been able to solve the issue by using a different version of the keytool to generate the ks file.  Apparently, the default settings for java on my machine refer to some old and outdated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve the issue by using a different version of the keytool to generate the ks file. Apparently, the default settings for java on my machine refer to some old and outdated version.

Comment: How did you change the version? And how can you verify the version?